# Ошибка при использовании connect в redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
        {this.props.test} // выводим тестовое свойство
        <div><input type="text" placeholder='First'/></div>
        <div><input type="text" placeholder='Second'/></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        test: '1',
    }
}

const WrapMainComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MainComponent);


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><WrapMainComponent/></Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Пытаюсь через коннект обернуть компонент что бы в дальнейшем иметь через пропсы иметь доступ к хранилщу.
Но в данный момент даже при тесте возникает ошибка, ниже на скрине.
В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: useMemo и остальные хуки недавно добавили. Может быть у вас React слишком старый?

Comment: да дело в реакте
обновил до новой верии